# SED command in linux to edit a file with script

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell, sed

I have a file name `temp.txt` with content as

```
ANSWER "1234:IDGK"
ANSWER "123456:DEF"
```

I need to change answer "1234:**$1**"with input parameter from script. 
Right now, I am using the code below in script (`run.sh`) to change the content in `temp.txt`

```
#!/bin/bash

Prompt1=$1

sed -i -e "s/\(1234:\).*/\1$1/"  temp.txt
```

But when I run the script with any input value {irrespective of length of value} **`"`** is over written in `temp.txt`.

for example

```
./run.sh ABCDEF
```

temp.txt is updated as

```
ANSWER "1234:ABCDEF
ANSWER "123456:DEF"
```

The expected output is

```
ANSWER "1234:ABCDEF"
ANSWER "123456:DEF"
```

Note: input value in file will always not be same so I can't go with

```
sed s/IDGK/ABCDEF/g
```

Please suggest correct SED command which will replace the only text and not the **`"`**.

Comment: what a mess?  Could you please clean up this post, you'll have a far better chance of an answer.

Comment: `sed -i` isn't a POSIX-standardized option, by the way -- not all implementations of `sed` have it, so if you need to be portable, it's best not to rely on it.

Comment: Frankly, variable substitution with `sed` isn't a great idea to start with when you don't have at least some control over the destination string -- what if `$1` contains a literal `/`, or -- worse -- a `/` followed by a `;` and another `sed` command? It's much safer to use `awk` in this kind of case, which allows arbitrary variables to be passed in out-of-band.

Comment: See for instance the definition of `gsub_literal` in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021 for an example of a way to do this safely.

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't want the trailing double quote deleted, you need to exclude it from the substitution.  For example:

```
sed -i -e "s/\(1234:\).*\(.\)/\1$1\2/"  temp.txt
```

The second capture matches the last character on the line, the double quote.

Or:

```
sed -i -e 's/\(1234:\)[^"]*'"/\1$1/"  temp.txt
```

Instead of matching any character, only match characters that are not double quotes.  Note the use of single quotes and double quotes to ensure the double quote in the negated character class is a double quote.  Alternatively again:

```
sed -i -e "s/\(1234:\)[^\"]*/\1$1/"  temp.txt
```

This escapes the double quote with a backslash.  It isn't the way I'd do it, but it will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
sed -i -e 's/\(1234:\).*/\1'$1'"/'  temp.txt
```

Last character will be the double quotes. So you can directly place that in the substitution. Or else you can try this.

```
sed -i -e 's/\(1234:\)[^"]*/\1'$1'/'  temp.txt
```

If your system not allow to use the `-i` option, you can use the redirect like this.

```
sed -e 's/\(1234:\)[^"]*/\1'$1'/'  temp.txt > temp.txt
```